# MongoDB + C# Driver + Geospatial fields querying - How to define location property on entities

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm running version 2.06 of Mongodb and version (1.5) of the C# driver supplied by 10Gen.

I want to have latitude and longitude coordinates on one of my entities so I can query entities using GeoNear or Query.WithinCircle.

I am adding a strongly typed Location object to my entity and then creating an index on the Location object that is hanging off my entity, but I can't get any GeoNear queries to work.

This is what my Location entity looks like.

```
public class Location
{
    [BsonDefaultValue(null)]
    public Nullable<double> lon { get; set; }

    [BsonDefaultValue(null)]
    public Nullable<double> lat { get; set; }  
}
```

This is how my entity in question looks.

```
  public class SomeEntity
  {
   public string Field1 {get; set;}

   // more fields here...

   public Location Loc {get; set;}
  }
```

I have found this link http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing/  and see that my location field needs to be an array.   What would my entity, SomeEntity, look like with an array field instead of my Location object?

I know this is simple I just can't figure it out! :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public string Field1 {get; set;}

    // more fields here...

   public double[] Loc {get; set;}
}
```

Although your existing class should have worked (while arrays are recommended the only real requirement is that the object consist of two numbers). I probably wouldn't use Nullable<double> and just use double instead.

In what way was your geo query not working?

Comment: Hi @Robert Stam -   Thanks for the input.  I assumed my location object should work as well as it simply provided two numbers.

My geo query was not returning any data.   Here is what it looked like..

var options = GeoNearOptions.SetMaxDistance(100 / this.EarthRadius);

var activeUsers = Query.EQ("Active",true);

var potentialUsers = userCollection.GeoNear(activeUsers, nDestinationLatitude, nDestinationLongitude,5,options);


An index was established on the data using the following code

userCollection.EnsureIndex("IndexKeys.GeoSpatial("loc"));

Comment: Sorry I tried to format my comments code, but couldn't find the syntax :-)

Comment: I found the issue!    When I defined the index I used "loc" when the name of my field is actually Loc, case sensitive.   

Thanks